# What is Microsoft Silverlight?

Tags: windows-xp, thinkpad, silverlight

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is Silverlight and how is different from flash? Why should I install it?](https://superuser.com/questions/29168/what-is-silverlight-and-how-is-different-from-flash-why-should-i-install-it)

What are the pros and cons of installing it on XP Pro, Thinkpad T60?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's basically Microsoft's version of flash. It is a web application framework initially made for video streaming, but now has many more features and .NET language support. The majority of videos on Microsoft's website are using it, and other sites are popping up using it as well. If you use MSDN or are interested in any of the programming video tutorials on their site, Silverlight is a must have. More on it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Silverlight).

Comment: Are they interchangeable? Do I just need one?
Thanks.

Comment: No they aren't interchangeable, if you enjoy your YouTube videos and browser games and such you'll want to keep flash.

Answer (score 2):

There is not really any cons of installing it.

Where as Flash is basically a way for people to make rich web experiences and now is porting to desktop (AIR), Silverlight is sort of Microsoft's way of making their Desktop WCF go to the web in a cut down version.

It has some cool features such as smooth streaming, and with every release it gets better and better, however I just can't see it taking over from flash any time soon.

Anyway, it is a low footprint and there are some cool sites such as the [Memorabilia section on Hard Rock Cafe](http://memorabilia.hardrock.com/)

---

FYI, I wrote this in a previous question and I think it applies here.

Silverlight is basically Microsoft's take on flash.

Everyone knows what Flash is, but the difference is that Silverlight is basically a cross platform (almost) version of what ActiveX should of been (eh... sort of!)- It enables developers to make Rich applications that are sandboxed from the rest of your computer.

At the moment, Flash is still the winner in my books, but Silverlight has many really cool features - [This is my favourite for a demonstration of variable bitrate video streaming.](http://www.iis.net/media/experiencesmoothstreaming)

Neither of these technologies will go away any time soon, personally I would still use Flash as Silverlight does not yet have the same reach, but it certainly is one to watch and is getting better all the time.

---

Musicfreak wrote-

Silverlight is basically Flash that runs on the .NET framework. So theoretically, it's better than Flash, but its market penetration isn't even close, so that's the only real drawback.